# conditionally instantiate a service in nestJs DI

Tags: nestjs

I have tow classes,  `FilesLocalService` that is needed to be loaded only in dev mode, and `FilesCloudService` that is needed to be loaded only in prod mode

so I do something like this:

```
 providers: [
    {
      provide: FilesService,
      useClass: 
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
          ? FilesLocalService
          : FilesCloudService,
    },

    //<------ This makes Nestjs always instantiate both services 
    FilesLocalService, 
    FilesCloudService
  ],
```

the problem is that both `FilesLocalService` and `FilesCloudService` are loaded in both prod and dev modes
I need Nestjs to instantiate only the required class based on the current environment

also, I need to let Nestjs resolve both without manually initiating the class, i.e. by using `useFactory`

**solving:**

the problem occurred because I added both `FilesLocalService` and `FilesCloudService` in `exports[]`, so we needed to provide them.
by removing them from `exports[]`, we could remove them too from `providers[]`

Answer (score 1):

you could write a dynamic module that will return the right provider depending on some condition like this:

```
export class Foo {
  static register(env: 'local' | 'cloud') {
    let provider;
    if (env === 'local') provider = FilesLocalService;
    if (env === 'cloud') provider = FilesCloudService;
    return {
     module: Foo,
     providers: [{provide: FilesService, useClass:provider}],
     exports: [FilesService],
   };
  }
}
```

then just import it in the module that will use the `FilesService` provider: `Foo.register(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'local' : 'cloud')`

Comment: I think this still produces the same issue because Nestjs needs to know how to instantiate both `FilesLocalService` and `FilesCloudService`, so wee need to add them to providers[]

Comment: that's no true. The token is `FilesService`, and the value will be defined by the class you've declared in `useClass`. Nestjs doesn't need to be aware of all the classes you would like to support if all of them are following the same interface.